# C++ pointer as return type from function

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to programming in C++. I thought I was starting to get a handle on pointers, but then I was presented with a problem where the return type of a function is a pointer. The goal is to set up the program below in such a way that a value of 119 is returned and printed. I can't quite figure out the function definition of f4.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* f4(int param);

int main()
{
    cout << f4(118);
    return 0;
}

int* f4(int parm)
{
    //I don't know how to make this work
}
```

*edit People are asking for more information. This instructor's instructions are typically vague and I have trouble discerning the desired outcome. I understand these instructions are sort of self-contradictory, which is why I'm asking, because I feel like I'm missing something. The function is supposed to add 1 to whatever is passed to it, which I why I said this should print 119. I pass 118 to the function, and the line cout << f4(118) should print 119.

Comment: That goal is self-contradictory. You are saying that the function must return a pointer. And at the same time you are saying that it must return `119`. `119` is not a pointer. `119` is an integer. You need to decide what it is you want to return: a pointer or an integer. Anyway, what is that `118` doing there in your code and why it is passed as an argument to `f4`? How is that `118` related to the the expected return value of `119`?

Comment: The question seems quite pointless, and I'm not even sure whether casting an integer to a pointer is guaranteed to give the same numerical result. Edit: nope - *A pointer converted
to an integer of sufficient size (if any such exists on the implementation) and back to the same pointer type
will have its original value; mappings between pointers and integers are otherwise implementation-defined.*

Comment: There sure is some lack of information here. What exactly do you want `f4` to return? Is it a pointer to dynamically allocated memory?

Comment: Wild guess, were you asked to create a function that returns a pointer or a function that uses a pointer to return a value?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are allowed to change the line `cout << f4(118);` ?   (note that this may not produce any output anyway since it has no trailing newline)

Comment: @MattMcNabb I had that same question. I was able to make it work when I called cout << *f4(118), but the instructor makes it sound like that isn't what we're supposed to do. The responses I'm getting makes it seem like I'm not crazy and that this problem isn't as clear as it should be.

Comment: Well, the problem here isn't well defined, so it's hard to give any help here. The answers you have here are all shots in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int *f4(int x)
{
    std::cout << (x + 1) << std::endl;
    std::fclose(stdout);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << f4(118);
}
```

Voilà!

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I see, let's try another way...

If you need to return pointer from a function, the only reasonable usage is with array:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* f4(int * a, int max)
{
    a[0]++;
    int * p = &a[0];
    return p;
}

void main()
{
    const int max = 5; 
    int a[max]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int * pnt = f4(a,max);
    cout<<*pnt;
}
```

In this example, function is returning a pointer to incremented first member of the array.

Comment: I failed to find your logic here. You're not even using all of the array, nor the second argument.

Comment: Second argument is just a "habit" - it's usually needed for traversing an array.